# pipe with exec C shell programme implementation

Tags: c, linux, shell, system-calls, pipeline

Trying  to implement shell programm  I got the following situation.

I want to implement piping at least a single level(not chained)
example 
I want my shell to excute for the follwing command

```
ls | less
```

here is my snipts

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];
    char buffer[1024];      

    pipe(fd);
    pid=fork();


    if(pid==0){

        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1],1);
        close(fd[1]);

        execlp( "ls","ls",NULL);
        exit(0);

    }else{

        //parent
        wait(NULL);
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0],buffer,sizeof(buffer));  // the parent reads the output of the last command 
                                        // from stdout 
        //printf("Recived:: %s\n",buffer); //for debugging --- and it works(got the output of the last command printed)!

        pid=fork();
        if(!pid){

            //printf("In new  child ::%s\n",buffer);// this line stil works

            **/**   !! HERE IS THE ISSUE **/**
            // I want to pass the a filename as an argument to the next command 
            // in this case for less 
            // someting like this execlp("less","less",filename.ext,NULL);

            // my question is how can I get file name in this situation

            //I tried to get file struct from the file discriptor and the tried to get
            // file name from that file , but faild!
            //FILE * file=fdopen(fd[0],"r+");
            //file->name;

            execlp("less","less",buffer ,NULL);

        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you read data yourself in "parent"? Just do (mostly) the same than in child (deal with file descriptors and dup and spawn your less)

Comment: Can you give me some example or link how to do that!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: If the question is "How do I mimic the shell's behavior in creating a pipeline?", the thing you seem to be missing is that you should create a child process for *each* of the commands.  Use `dup2()` to make the first use the write end of your pipe as its `stdout`, and again to make the second process use the read end as its `stdin`.  Then have each subprocess exec the appropriate command.  Be sure each process, including the parent, closes the end(s) of the pipe that it is not, itself using.  You do not need to manually forward data from one process to another.